# can i treat a flowlayoutpanel like a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, flowlayoutpanel

is there ways to have a selecteditem and detect when it changes.

what is the recommended best practices for wanting to have listbox type behavior but i dont have strings, i have user controls that i want to list from top to bottom.

is flowlayoutpanel the correct way to do this or is there any other way that gives me the listbox behavior and events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the GotFocus event on your controls in your usercontrols to determine when they get the focus.

Alternatively you could use a DataGridView control, adding the UserControls to a custom column on it. There's an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN on this, basically you implement the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface in your usercontrol.